# Dovecot, mail crypt plugin

Tags: email, encryption, dovecot

I am developing a mail server with dovecot and now I need to encrypt all the mails before storing and decrypt them when reading. I recently found a plugin for dovecot called mail crypt. Dovecot wiki is little bit hard to understand. Would you please suggest a good tutorial for that or is there any other good plugin for encrypt emails for dovecot?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, update "dovecot.conf" with below lines

```
mail_plugins = $mail_plugins mail_crypt
mail_attribute_dict = file:%h/Maildir/dovecot-attributes

plugin {
    mail_crypt_curve = prime256v1
    mail_crypt_save_version = 2
}
```